# ошибка компиляции Opencl gcc

Tags: c++

cl_image_desc desc; просит заменить на cl_image_info desc;

Ошибка: запрос для члена 'image_type' в 'desc', который относится к классу non-class 'cl_image_info {aka unsigned int}' вот код:

'class Image2D: public Изображение 
{
public: Image2D (const Контекст и контекст, флаги cl_mem_flags, формат ImageFormat, :: size_t width, void * host_ptr = NULL, cl_int * err = NULL) {// desc

```
    cl_int error;
    cl_image_desc desc;
    desc.image_type = CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D;
    desc.image_width = width;
    desc.image_row_pitch = 0;
    desc.num_mip_levels = 0;
    desc.num_samples = 0;
    desc.buffer = 0;
    object_ = ::clCreateImage3D(
        context(),
        flags,
        &format,
        &desc,
        host_ptr,
        &error);
```

Помогите пожалуйста.заранее благодарен

Comment: `cl_image_deck` наверное должно быть `cl_image_desc`, поставьте себе нормальный компилятор без такой гуглетранслейт локализации.

Comment: случайно опечатался.но в коде не в этом дело

Comment: @VTT не подскажите какой лучше будет и как удалить старый?